# Indicator for sudden movement of price

Tags: indicator

I tried to find a method to recognize a sudden movement, e.g. climb, of a stock price. The method should realize that the price suddenly changes in value very fast, after having a long calm period. What would be a suitable method (indicator) to achieve that?

I tried to search online for that, but out of all explanations how different indicators work, I can not determine which one is the most suitable.

Comment: Some variation of Moving Average comparison should do: for example Kaufman Adaptive Moving Average, or moving average with a variable band, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Volatility Bands](http://www.sharechart.com.au/Education/TechnicalIndicators/Volatility%20Bands.htm) may be what you need. From the link:

> Volatility Bands are an indicator that allows users to compare volatility and relative price levels over a period time. The indicator consists of three bands designed to encompass the majority of a security's price action.
>
> Volatility bands can help confirm trend, but they do not determine the future direction of a security.

Answer (score 1):

Bollinger Bandwidth would do the job. Bollinger Bandwidth is defined as the percentage difference of standard deviation bands of a moving average.